# What are possible reasons javascript files don't successfully load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, underscore.js

I am trying to import JQuery and Underscore.js into a webpage. This is what my script tags look like:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Messing Around</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" scr="assets/javascripts/underscore.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascripts/app.js"></script>
</head>
```

I also tried using an underscore.js library hosted on a CDN.

With just this in the app.js file,

```
var data =   {name: 'Ed',
              age : '25',
              city: 'Toronto'}, 
template =   'Welcome, <%= name %>, you are <%= age %> years old and from <%= city %>';
var parsedTemplate = _.template(template,  data );
```

In the browser console, I am getting the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined

Which makes me believe the library is not being loaded correctly.

Any indications why that might be? the route to underscore.js is spelled correctly. I am drawing a blank.

Comment: You haven't shown where you're getting the actual error from.

Comment: Hi, if you're getting that error in the browser console, you can look for the line of code and paste that in here. That may help us understand the problem a bit better.

Comment: can you confirm you can load the undercore.js library manually?  i.e. if you type in your browser: `http://<your_ip>/<your-app>/assets/javascripts/underscore.js`  are you able to see the file?  - ALSO, sounds like you are using the functions from your `app.js` file but at load time, you have no guaranties that the file has finished loading when you try to use it.  You may want to do this after document ready instead....

Comment: @Nit I edited to show my app.js file. With this script, I'm just trying to verify the library being correctly loaded. The error is on line 5, the only mention of " _. "

Comment: @ochi yes it works, I can open it fine

Comment: If you call the page, can you see it as resource loaded on the dev tools console? (assuming Chrome dev tools but FF has a similar feature)

Comment: @ochi i wrapped it with a ready and with a page:load, but still same issue. Not sure what you mea by calling it, but yea if I go to the sources tab in chrome dev tools the file isn't there?!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `underscore.js` has not loaded yet by the time you are invoking it.

Try adding this to your `app.js` file to invoke it after document ready.

```
$(function(){
    var data =   {name: 'Ed',
                  age : '25',
                  city: 'Toronto'}, 
    template =   'Welcome, <%= name %>, you are <%= age %> years old and from <%= city %>';
    var parsedTemplate = _.template(template,  data );
});
```

Comment: weird... any firewall rules blocking it?  what's the response you get in the dev tools Network panel when it calls the underscore.js file? (404?) or something else?

Comment: it doesn't even show up, just the html file and app.js do (which are the only others)

Comment: this may sound silly but can you look at the source of the page and ensure you are loading the correct version on the browser? (done that myself a few times, that's why I am asking)

Comment: thanks for your help ochi. I fired up a local server and it works now; strange

Comment: very strange... hard to tell from here what the cause might be... glad you sorted it out :)